# simplify nested Objects and find sum of particular property

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a nested Objects like below. I want to simplify the nested Objects to one Object and find sum of a particular property of all the children of the particular parent Object.

**Current Object**

```
let obj = {
Myanmar: [
    {
        trk1: {
            mou: 0.0,
            ca: 1.0,
            ccs: 0.0,
            ccc: 0.0,
        },
    }
],
Gibraltar: [
    {
        trk1: {
            mou: 12.850000381469727,
            ca: 1.0,
            ccs: 1.0,
            ccc: 3.0,
        },
    }
],
Cyprus: [
    {
        trk1: {
            mou: 36.25,
            ca: 3.0,
            ccs: 2.0,
            ccc: 7.0,
        },
        trk2: {
            mou: 27.299999237060547,
            ca: 1.0,
            ccs: 1.0,
            ccc: 6.0,
        },
        trk3: {
            mou: 80.59999752044678,
            ca: 4.0,
            ccs: 4.0,
            ccc: 14.0,
        },
        trk4: {
            mou: 26.716670513153076,
            ca: 4.0,
            ccs: 4.0,
            ccc: 6.0,
        }
    }
]};
```

**Expected Object**

```
{
Myanmar: {
    mou: "(trk1-mou+trk2-mou+trk3-mou)",
    ca: "(trk1-ca+trk2-ca+trk3-ca)"
}};
```

I want to perform the sum of properties over a nested object.
i am not able to continue after getting the object.keys
please help.

Comment: The JSON you provided is not valid. Please share a valid javascript object, in the fomat `let obj = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```js
var obj={"Myanmar": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 0.0, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0 }}],"Gibraltar": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 12.850000381469727, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 1.0, "ccc": 3.0 }}],"Cyprus": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 36.25, "ca": 3.0, "ccs": 2.0, "ccc": 7.0 }, "trk2": { "mou": 27.299999237060547, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 1.0, "ccc": 6.0 }, "trk3": { "mou": 80.59999752044678, "ca": 4.0, "ccs": 4.0, "ccc": 14.0 }, "trk4": { "mou": 26.716670513153076, "ca": 4.0, "ccs": 4.0, "ccc": 6.0 }}]}

result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k,v])=>{
 acc[k] = acc[k] || {};
 Object.entries(v[0]).forEach(([_, country])=>{
 for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(country)){
     acc[k][key] = acc[k][key] || 0;
     acc[k][key] += value;
   }
 })
 return acc;
},{});


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj={"Myanmar": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 0.0, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 0.0, "ccc": 0.0 }}],"Gibraltar": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 12.850000381469727, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 1.0, "ccc": 3.0 }}],"Cyprus": [{ "trk1": { "mou": 36.25, "ca": 3.0, "ccs": 2.0, "ccc": 7.0 }, "trk2": { "mou": 27.299999237060547, "ca": 1.0, "ccs": 1.0, "ccc": 6.0 }, "trk3": { "mou": 80.59999752044678, "ca": 4.0, "ccs": 4.0, "ccc": 14.0 }, "trk4": { "mou": 26.716670513153076, "ca": 4.0, "ccs": 4.0, "ccc": 6.0 }}]}

let reqObj={};
let arr = Object.keys(obj);
for(var i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
 let inObj = obj[arr[i]][0];
 reqObj[arr[i]] = Object.keys(inObj).reduce((acc,ele,index)=>{
     let keyArr = Object.keys(inObj[ele]);
     for(var j=0;j<=keyArr.length-1;j++){
       acc = {...acc,...{[keyArr[j]] : (keyArr[j] in acc)   ? acc[keyArr[j]] + inObj[ele][keyArr[j]]   : inObj[ele][keyArr[j]]}}
     }
     return acc;
  },{})
}
  console.log(reqObj)
```